# wxTimer runs on startup. Need to Start it when needed.(wxWidgets, Code::Blocks, C++)

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

This is probably a silly wx newbie question, but I'm new to this IDE.

When using the `wxTimer`, adding it to a `wxFrame`, it runs on startup.  I can Stop it and Start it after my app launches, but initially it runs.

Using the `wxTimer` starts with adding it to a `wxFrame`.  Then double-click the new `wxTimer` control icon to create an event as such:

```
void wxSQLi_417Frame::OnTimer1Trigger(wxTimerEvent& event)
{
     DisUpdate();
}
```

This now fires with adding a `Timer1.Start();`
How can it be idle on startup, until sending a

```
Timer2.Start();
```

?

Comment: how do you create a timer? how do you know it fires? Are you sure you didn't call Start() somewhere and forgot about it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_timer.html#a0560894a1ab57792f52992ffbc58e735):

> In any case, you must start the timer with `wxTimer::Start()` after
>   constructing it before it actually starts sending notifications.

So if your timer is running, you must have started it explicitly.

Comment: Yes Neil, true.I found this line under the Initializations,
       Timer2.Start(1000, true);  and deleted it.
Thanks

Comment: I constructed a timer dynamically and used 'kill_timer->StartOnce(500);' to run once.